# DIY UV Exposure Unit for Making PCBs

Tags: pcb, uv

I'd like to buy or build a UV exposure unit for the photoresist method of making my own PCBs.

Nice-to-haves:

- adjustable timer knob
- works for double-sided PCBs
- US$50 budget

What are my options?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Making one for $50 with those features is going to be difficult. Here is my very simple one:

[image: Here]

It's made from MDF and some strips of wood, held together with some glue and wood screws. A sheet of ordinary window glass rests on the upper wood strips.

I used standard 12" fluorescent light fittings, disassembled, with the tubes replaced by UV tubes. They are connected to a piece of mains cable and a mains plug.

I time the exposure (11 minutes) with the kitchen timer on my Dell Streak tablet. Although it's very crude, I get excellent results - 8/8 mil tracks if necessary - with transparencies printed on my cheap inkjet printer.

It cost me the equivalent of about $40.

You could build a basic unit like mine, and add the bells and whistles later.

Some members of the Homebrew PCB Yahoo group are using UV LEDs, but they are far more expensive than a couple of UV tubes. Enough LEDs for a small board could cost over $100, IIRC.

Comment: Do you have time to describe the circuit? I'm new to fluorescent lamps.

Comment: It's quite obvious if you buy standard 12" fluorescent light fittings. The ballasts should have the connections on them.